# why is the event function fired when i click anywhere on the page

Tags: javascript

Why is the event function fired when i click anywhere on the page?

First when you load the page the event function only triggers when i focus over the form input fields. But then when I click anywhere on the page the event function `helperNote` is fired. Why is that?

```js
var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form-container p input:not([type="submit"])');

for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {
  var inputField = allInputs[i];
  var inputFieldId = inputField.id;
  var getInput = document.getElementById(inputFieldId);
  getInput.addEventListener('focus', helperNote, false);
}

function helperNote(e) {
  console.log('helperNote');
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-container">
    <p>Fill The Form Below</p>
    <p id="helperNote">Helper note Appears Here</p>
    <p>
      <label>Email :</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Name :</label>
      <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Age :</label>
      <input type="number" name="age" id="age">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="sign-up">
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Seems to be working just fine for me.... The function only appears to be running when the focus is true on those elements. https://jsfiddle.net/wyjbuohy/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x11hd848/ works fine for me

Comment: Works fine for me on Firefox, what browser are you testing on?

Comment: I am using chrome

Comment: @ContentSolutions I am also using google chrome and all seems to function just fine. Please take a look at the jsfiddle provided in my previous comment.

Comment: yes it seems to be working fine

Comment: i used a breakpoint in chrome to debug the code, could be bcoz of that maybe.